# While running Hadoop map reduce job using java Null pointer exception is being thrown

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

Thanks in advance...

I am running Hadoop version 0.20.0 and HBase 0.94. I have an aggregation logic which will run every night 12'o clock using scheduler. We are in stage where we cannot upgrade HBase and Hadoop. While running MapReduce job it is throwing Exception as follows,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLocalPath(Configuration.java:877)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getLocalPath(JobConf.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:800)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
```

While running stand alone it is working fine and no exceptions are being thrown.

Please help us regarding this...

Comment: @Dragan Bozanovic : Error is being thrown inside framework. Not from my code.

Answer (score 1):

By looking to the definition of getLocalPath : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-with-200-826/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.java#Configuration.getLocalPath%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29

It seems, if I have the right version of the file, that the `String dirsProp` doesn't contain informations about directories. I'm guessing that String[] dirs = `getStrings(dirsProp);` is returning null.

Wild guess here is that you've got a missing configuration about a directory in Hadoop.